# What is the most efficient search mechanism for this situation?

Tags: c#, list, search

I have a class that is defined as follows:

```
public class AlarmViolation
{
    public string ObjectId { get; set; }
    public int ChartType { get; set; }
    public string AlarmInternalId { get; set; }
    public short PositionInSequence { get; set; }
    public short SequenceCount { get; set; }
    public string TagValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurgeDate { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create a List of this class as follows:

```
List<AlarmViolation> alarmViolationList;
```

I currently execute a Linq query as follows:

```
return alarmViolationList
  .Where(row => row.ObjectId == objectId)
  .Where(row => row.ChartType == this.ChartType)
  .Where(row => row.AlarmInternalId == this.InternalId)
  .Where(row => row.PositionInSequence == positionInSequence)
  .Where(row => row.SequenceCount == sequenceCount)
  .Any();
```

I am getting pretty bad performance with my current implementation. The list will typically contain somewhere between 150K and 300K entries. This query is executed hundreds of times on a regular schedule (roughly every 3 minutes).

If I could somehow index this list, or if this were a database table, I would create an index on ObjectId + ChartType.

Could someone suggest a more efficient implementation. If you need more information, I would be glad to provide it.

Comment: If I were to answer this, I'd basically repeat both usr's answer and Nawaz; they're not mutually exclusive so you can use the comparison order change Nawaz suggests in the `IEquality<AlarmViolation>` implementation you'd want to go with for usr's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I could somehow index this list, or if this were a database table, I would create an index on ObjectId + ChartType.

That suggests you should create a key type (`AlarmViolationKey`?) consisting of the ObjectId and ChartType, then use a `Dictionary<AlarmViolationKey, AlarmViolation>`. That will *radically* enhance the search time. If you have more than one violation per key, *and* you've created the list up-front in a way where it won't be changing, you could use a `Lookup` instead.

Whatever you do, basically you don't want to do the linear scan you're currently doing - you want a hash-based lookup.

(Depending on your exact situation, you may still need a list, or you may be able to use a dictionary instead of the list completely. It's hard to say without any more context.)

Answer (score 1):

As you only search for equality, I suggest you use a hashtable. Create a class that will hold all members which you equality-search on (in your case: ObjectId, ChartType, AlarmInternalId, ...). Implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Next, put all your objects into a lookup table using either `Enumerable.ToDictionary` or `Enumerable.ToLookup`. You can use that newly created "key" class to add the items and to search for items.

This will give you constant time lookup, even for multiple results.

Comment: Or since the only thing of interest is the "key", then use a HashSet (or if you really like the linqyness create a `ToHashSet` of `public static HashSet<TSource> ToHashSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src){ return source.ToHashSet(); }`

Comment: Great idea with that extension method. Anyway, I was preparing for the possibility that the "key" is not a key (there might be multiple matching elements).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write this:

```
return alarmViolationList
      .Any(row => row.ChartType == this.ChartType &&              //int
                  row.PositionInSequence == positionInSequence && //short
                  row.SequenceCount == sequenceCount &&           //short
                  row.AlarmInternalId == this.InternalId &&       //string
                  row.ObjectId == objectId);                      //string
```

This should improve the performance by some amount, in my opinion. Note that I'm doing `string` comparison **after** `int` and `short` comparisons, taking advantage of short-circuits.

Comment: Still a linear scan. This is hardly any better.

Comment: @usr, unless there's a very large number of items that all have the same `ChartType`, then this will do that linear scan more quickly. "Linear" means O(n) means n * k, and this likely has a smaller value for k than that in the question - based on the fact that int and short comparison is in itself O(1) while string comparison is in itself O(n). Knowledge of which values are more likely to match or not match with the data use can also improve this further.

Comment: @Nawaz from the question: `The list will typically contain somewhere between 150K and 300K entries`